# Evaluate user expression against object

Tags: c#, nuget

Lets say the user has supplied  a string with an expression like
**"if {quantity} > 9 then {price} = {price}*0.8"** and an array like

```
[ 
 {line : 1, quantity : 5, price : 500 },
 {line : 2, quantity : 15, price : 1500},
 {line : 3, quantity : 8, price : 800 },
 {line : 4, quantity : 10, price : 1000 },
]
```

then it would return an array like

```
[ 
 {line : 1, quantity : 5, price : 500 },
 {line : 2, quantity : 15, price : 1200},
 {line : 3, quantity : 8, price : 800 },
 {line : 4, quantity : 10, price : 800 },
]
```

Is there a function or library in c# for evaluating objects and arrays of objects against strings?

Comment: the short answer is: no. the long answer is: no, you've gotta parse and interpret the string yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Althrough the syntax of your sample not a c# syntax, but if you can use c# syntax then look around these namespaces:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting

E.g. to evaluate a lamba expression available as string and containing references to your domain model:

```cs
// import your namespace
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.AddImports("YourModel");

// refer you assemblies
scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddReferences(typeof(YourType).Assembly);

// evaluate
var ret = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Expression<Func<YourType, bool>>>(
      lambdaString, 
      scriptOptions)
   .Result;
```

Certainly there are many risks having user's "code strings" evaluated runtime.
Take care.